# random sampling from a table

Tags: mysql, sql, random, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have an original table

`full_table`

```
patientID    gender     age

hash1        male       25
hash2        male       24
hash3        female     43
hash4        female     45
...
```

I am trying to create a random subset of the above table using the table below such that I end up with 2x the value in the count column with the following conditions:

`summary_table`

```
gender    age     count

male      42      5
female    65      3
```

Basically, I would like to pull 10 rows from the `full_table` where `age=42 and gender="male"` in addition to 6 rows where `gender="female" and age=62`.

The results could look like this:

```
patientID    gender     age

hash49       male       42
hash19273    male       42
hash1324     male       42
... *7
hash123      female     62
hash5346     female     62
hash132      female     62
... *3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use window functions to enumerate the rows in the main table.  Then join in the counts and filter:

```
select m.*
from (select m.*,
             row_number() over (partition by gender, age order by rand()) as seqnum
      from maintable m
     ) m join
     summary_table s
     on s.gender = m.gender and s.age = m.age
where m.seqnum <= s.count * 2;
```